# Git branches and settings.py pointing to specific database

Tags: django, git, git-branch

When I switch to a new branch, say "dev", I have to manually change/edit my django settings.py file to use a development 'dev' database.

Is there a convenient way to automate this? I.e. when I switch to 'dev', the settings.py in 'dev' branch is already using the values pointing to my 'dev' database.

Even better if I can extend this automation to any new branches and corresponding new databases I create for each corresponding branch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, what i do is have a file called settings_local.py in my development branch where i specify my database and other settings only for said branch and then at the end of my settings.py i add

```
try:
    execfile(os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'settings_local.py'), globals(), locals())
except IOError, err:
    pass
```

so in my production environment i don't have a settings_local.py file, so the settings remain the same, all you would have to do is add the settings_local.py ( or whatever you name it to your .gitignore file

Comment: I am using this solution in my existing set-up but I am looking for a more sophisticated one that allows me to branch at whim without needing to bother with manually changing the DATABASE NAME. And it's specifically for dealing with my local development environment where I may create new branches at whim (and instantiate corresponding new databases at whim) to try out new features etc.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at smudge/clean scripts. You can forego having a dev branch. You can see the writeup on  in the "git attributes" chapter.

Answer (score 0):

When you **create** new branch, you have to **edit** settings.py only **once**

Comment: This is what I thought at first too, but then merging dev into master will be a problem.

Comment: Problem?! When manual resolving of conflicts in code became problem *for developer*?

Comment: I don't think the OP wants to have to resolve the conflict every time a merge is made. He wants the settings.py in master to remain the same, despite the settings.py in dev being different (at least as far as the DATABASE NAME is concerned).